# How to update servercount automatically after bot is added to a server

Tags: discord.js

I'm having some trouble with automating my bots servercount in its status whenever it gets added to a server, but the member count updates as expected, the server count is the one that is not updating (I have to restart my bot to get it to update the server count).

ready.js

```
const client = require("../index");
const config = require("../botconfig");
const chalk = require('chalk');

client.on("ready", () => {
  client.logger.log("READY", `${client.user.tag} has logged in!`)
  
  const arrayOfStatus = [
    { name: `version ${config.version} | ${config.defaultPrefix}help`, type: 'PLAYING'},
    { name: `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`, type: 'WATCHING'},
    { name: `${client.users.cache.size} users`, type: 'WATCHING'}
  ];
  
  let index = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    if (index === arrayOfStatus.length) index = 0;
    const status = arrayOfStatus[index];
    client.user.setActivity(status);
    index++;
  }, 5000);
  
  const clientDetails = {
    guilds: client.guilds.cache.size,
    users: client.users.cache.size, 
  };
});
```

Comment: Have you considered listening to the [guildCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) and [guildDelete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildDelete) events?

Comment: I have, it did not seem to work as intended, or what I though it would've done.